# How to get reason from custom error enum on Swift failure Result

Tags: xcode, swiftui

In order to track server errors from a Restfull Api on an SwiftUI IOS App I am feeding the error message from NSData to the "reason" parameter of next NetworkErrors enum:

```
enum NetworkError: Error {
    case domainError(reason:String)
    case decodingError(reason:String)
    case encodingError(reason:String)
}
```

The error reason is fed when decoding the NSURLSession response:

```
static func postRequest<T:Decodable, U:Codable>(_ endpoint:String, _ input:U?, completion: @escaping (Result<T,NetworkError>) -> Void) {
        ...
                 do {
                     let retval = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
                     completion(.success(retval))

                     } catch let DecodingError.dataCorrupted(context) {
                        let responseData = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                        completion(.failure(.decodingError(reason: responseData ?? "Data corrupted from response")))
                     } catch {
                         ...
                     }
    ...
}
```

The error reason should be available on next code, but I'm only able to print the localizedDescription:

```
Button(action:{
    self.postRequest(endpoint, self.value){ (result: Result<Bool,NetworkError>) in
        switch result {
                        case .success:
                            print("value saved successfully")
                        case .failure(let error):
                            print("failure to save value")
                            print(error.localizedDescription)                            
                        }
        }
    }){
        Image(systemName:"icloud.and.arrow.up")
    }
```

Comment: Use a switch to find out what error it actually is. You could do that as part of the existing (three `.failure` cases instead of one) or you could do it inside the single `.failure` case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `failure` case, we know that `error` is a NetworkError, so now disassemble that `error` with another switch:

```
switch error {
case .domainError(let reason): // do something
case .decodingError(let reason): // do something
case .encodingError(let reason): // do something
}
```

Comment: might you please share how to code it as part of the existing switch? I'm getting the error Pattern cannot match values of type 'Result<Bool, NetworkError>'

Comment: In a switch on `result` you would say `case .failure(.domainError(let reason))` and so on.